# What should I do to hide the pop-up menu from Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I made a pop-up menu.
I want to make the pop-up menu function visible or invisible compared to the current user's uid and the author's uid who wrote the post.
uid is the uid of the bulletin author account and mUid is the uid of the currently logged-in user.

How shall I do it?

```
    db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    if (user != null) {
        mEmail = user.getEmail();
        mUid = user.getUid();
    }
    popUpMenu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (uid != mUid) {
                PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(getApplicationContext(), v);
                getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_detail, popup.getMenu());
                popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                      @Override
                      public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                          switch (item.getItemId()) {
                              case R.id.post_update:
                                  Toast.makeText(DetailActivity.this, "Update", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                  break;
                              case R.id.post_delete:
                                  Toast.makeText(DetailActivity.this, "delete", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                  break;
                              default:
                                  break;
                          }
                          return false;
                      }
                });
                popup.show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(DetailActivity.this, "You are not the author.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: And what exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?

Comment: @AlexMamo When I am a creator with my login, when I click on the image, a pop-up menu appears.
However, my code doesn't show pop-up menus, only Toast messages.
if (uid != mUid) will be implemented.
uid is the uid of the bulletin author account and mUid is the uid of the currently logged-in user.